# Chrome shortcut to immediately get a word's pronunciation?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any chrome shortcut that you can press to have the word pronounced out loud just as though you'd opened a separate tab, typed the word in google, and clicked the sound icon to have it read out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the various [extensions available](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=google+chrome+extension+to+read+text+-chromebook).

If you find that they do not have a shortcut or easy access in general you can create a custom shortcut for them.

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? If it works for you, even if migrated, the accepted answer (if it works for you) will also be migrated providing useful information to users.

Comment: I prefer a shortcut, as installing extensions gives your browsing data to the (third party) extension developers

Comment: I do understand your concerns. Unfortunately I don't think there is a default Chrome functionality for this. *(Actually, I am quite sure.)*